No route to loopback IP through IPsec subnets
No route to loopback IP through IPsec subnetsFirst of all, please note that I do not have access to the remote equipment, i.e., the remote IPsec connection point. The communication has been established correctly, with the output of ipsec statusall being:
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.8.2, Linux 5.4.0-190-generic, x86_64):
  uptime: 22 minutes, since Aug 07 13:49:47 2024
  malloc: sbrk 1617920, mmap 0, used 640304, free 977616
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 4
  loaded plugins: charon aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac
gcm drbg attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark stroke updown eap-mschapv2 xauth-generic counters
Listening IP addresses:
  178.X.X.X
  172.17.200.1
  213.X.X.X
Connections:
       myvpn:  213.X.X.X...200.X.X.X  IKEv1
       myvpn:   local:  [213.X.X.X] uses pre-shared key authentication
       myvpn:   remote: [200.X.X.X] uses pre-shared key authentication
       myvpn:   child:  172.17.200.0/30 === 10.0.0.0/20 TUNNEL
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
       myvpn[2]: ESTABLISHED 22 minutes ago, 213.X.X.X[213.X.X.X]...200.X.X.X[200.X.X.X]
       myvpn[2]: IKEv1 SPIs: 68a1fb4ec428bf10_i 54d4d7683de06888_r*, pre-shared key reauthentication in 23 hours
       myvpn[2]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/MODP_2048
       myvpn{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP SPIs: c4433d18_i 9a7ba82e_o
       myvpn{1}:  AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/MODP_2048, 0 bytes_i, 1596 bytes_o (19 pkts, 980s ago), rekeying in 11 hours
       myvpn{1}:   172.17.200.0/30 === 10.0.0.0/20

The IPsec configuration in /etc/ipsec.conf is as follows:
conn %default
    ikelifetime=86400s
    keylife=43200s
    keyingtries=%forever
    ike=aes256-sha256-modp2048!
    esp=aes256-sha256-modp2048!
    rekeymargin=3m
    keyexchange=ikev1
    authby=secret
    mobike=no

conn myvpn
    keyexchange=ikev1
    left=213.X.X.X
    leftauth=psk
    leftsubnet=172.17.200.0/30
    right=200.X.X.X
    rightauth=psk
    rightsubnet=10.0.0.0/20
    auto=start
    ike=aes256-sha256-modp2048
    esp=aes256-sha256-modp2048
    ikelifetime=86400s
    keylife=43200s
    type=tunnel

Of course, I am pinging the remote server:
ping 200.X.X.X
PING 200.X.X.X (200.X.X.X) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 200.X.X.X: icmp_seq=1 ttl=236 time=211 ms
64 bytes from 200.X.X.X: icmp_seq=2 ttl=236 time=211 ms
...

However, when I try to ping the loopback (10.0.0.1) of the remote subnet (10.0.0.0/20), I do not receive a response.
ping 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4090ms

My network configuration is as follows:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:a1:ed:9a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 178.X.X.X/32 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 172.17.200.1/30 brd 172.17.200.3 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 213.X.X.X/32 scope global dynamic ens3
       valid_lft 65162sec preferred_lft 65162sec

The output of the ip xfrm state command:
src 213.X.X.X dst 200.X.X.X
        proto esp spi 0x9a7ba82e reqid 1 mode tunnel
        replay-window 0 flag af-unspec
        auth-trunc hmac(sha256) 0xd911f3814f0aba8bcce4321db4b5b92e268b9537722bbdc11024b9394bcf9f76 128
        enc cbc(aes) 0x7e2a11856aa671bff14cc218f21ca531b5bf49e3701edfa88e6f788bae3cb6b6
        anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0x18, bitmap 0x00000000
src 200.X.X.X dst X.X.X.X
        proto esp spi 0xc4433d18 reqid 1 mode tunnel
        replay-window 32 flag af-unspec
        auth-trunc hmac(sha256) 0xa4c0eda527183185480562d58e6d5702e159630cba8ab6f6f040b7673db5b0f7 128
        enc cbc(aes) 0xff6d359781154588967c1e9924f092008b72a4c138abe9446d595a087409fe7b
        anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0x0, bitmap 0x00000000

And ip xfrm policy:
src 172.17.200.0/30 dst 10.0.0.0/20
        dir out priority 374399
        tmpl src 213.X.X.X dst 200.X.X.X
                proto esp spi 0x9a7ba82e reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 10.0.0.0/20 dst 172.17.200.0/30
        dir fwd priority 374399
        tmpl src 200.X.X.X dst 213.X.X.X
                proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 10.0.0.0/20 dst 172.17.200.0/30
        dir in priority 374399
        tmpl src 200.X.X.X dst 213.X.X.X
                proto esp reqid 1 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        socket in priority 0
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        socket out priority 0
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        socket in priority 0
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
        socket out priority 0
src ::/0 dst ::/0
        socket in priority 0
src ::/0 dst ::/0
        socket out priority 0
src ::/0 dst ::/0
        socket in priority 0
src ::/0 dst ::/0
        socket out priority 0

The reason I believe the issue is on my side is that using tcpdump -i any icmp I don't see any output towards 10.0.0.1 even when pinging simultaneously. I understand that the route in IPsec is not being set up correctly, even if I add the route manually:
10.0.0.0/20 via 172.17.200.1 dev ens3

It still doesn’t work; same result. What additional checks would be appropriate to identify the problem?

Only packets with a source IP in 172.17.200.0/30 will get tunneled. So you need a route that selects such an IP as preferred source. strongSwan should install one in table 220 (check with ip route list table 220).

Checking the route list of table 220, the indicated IP should be correct: 10.0.0.0/20 via 213.X.X.X dev ens3 proto static src 172.17.200.1.

If you send messages (check the stats) but don't receive any, the problem is likely at the other end (or due to a firewall between the hosts).
